# Getting error when accessing .first or .second in map <std::pair<float,float>, std::vector<float> >

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, iterator

So I am trying to iterate over a map who's key is a pair of floats, and its' values are vectors of floats. I was following different examples on stackoverflow on how to access key and value, but I am having problems of using .first or .second . Here is my setup.

```
typedef std::pair<float, float> XYPair;
typedef std::map<XYPair, std::vector<float> > VectorsMap;

VectorsMap points;
VectorsMap::iterator iter;

//some function that spits back a VectorsMap map.
points = fileParser.parseFile();

//iterate over all vectors
for (iter = points.begin(); iter != points.end(); iter++) {
    XYPair key = iter.first;
}
```

**Here is the error:**

```
myMain.cpp: In function âint main(int, char**)â:
myMain.cpp:21: error: âstruct std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<float, float>, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >â has no member named âsecondâ
make: *** [myMain.o] Error 1
```

I have not used an iterator before so please cut me some slack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An iterator has a similar interface to a pointer. If you have a pointer `p` to a pair, you'd have to write `p->first` and `p->second`, not `p.first` and `p.second`.

Here, you'll want to write `XYPair key = iter->first;`